# Index for the end of a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a function that loads some data into a 2D numpy array. I want to let the function call specify a number of rows and columns that can be removed from the beginning and the end. If no parameter is specified, it returns all the data.

```
import numpy as np
function load_data(min_row, max_row, min_col, max_col):
    a = np.loadtxt('/path/to/mydata.txt')[min_row:max_row,min_col:max_col]
```

Now, `min_row` and `min_col` could default to `0`. How can I set the defaults for `max_col` and `max_row` to refer to the end of the array?

My only solution is:

```
function load_data(min_row=0, max_row=None, min_col=0, max_col=None):
    a = np.loadtxt('/path/to/mydata.txt')
    if not max_row: max_row = a.shape[0]
    if not max_col: max_col = a.shape[1]
    a = a[min_row:max_row,min_col:max_col]
```

Is there a better solution, something like:

```
function load_data(min_row=0, max_row="end", min_col=0, max_col="end"):
    a = np.loadtxt('/path/to/mydata.txt')[min_row:max_row,min_col:max_col]
```

For the record, example data could be:

```
np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
          [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
          [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
          [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
          [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]])
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just use `None` directly in the slice, for example,

```
x = np.arange(10)
x[2:None]    # array([5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

or you could write your function like:

```
function load_data(min_row=0, max_row=None, min_col=0, max_col=None):
    a = np.loadtxt('/path/to/mydata.txt')
    a = a[min_row:max_row,min_col:max_col]
```

Here, you could also replace you min defaults with `None` too.  This works because `None` is used as the defaults in the [slice object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice).  For more explicit docs on using `None` in numpy slicing, see the Note box at the end of the [Basic Slicing docs description](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing).

Comment: you can also just omit the `None` leading to `x[2:]` and `a[min_row:, min_col:]`